# Attaching an ImageResource from an external CSS file using @sprite

Tags: css, gwt, sprite, cssresource, clientbundle

I'm trying to use CssResource and ImageResource together in a GWT2.2 project.

CssResource and obfuscation are working properly, but I'm having problems accessing images.

I already can access the images through ImageResource directly from the ui.xml files in the following way:

```
<ui:with type="com.example.client.resource.ResourceBundle" field="myResource"/>
<g:Image resource="{myResource.image}"/>
```

But I cannot attach ImageResource from within external .css files using @sprite.

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface ResourceBundle extends ClientBundle {
ResourceBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create (ResourceBundle.class);

    @Source("com/example/client/resource/images/image.png")
    ImageResource image();

    @Source("com/example/client/resource/css/mystyle.css")
    MyCssResource myCssResource();
    }

public interface MyCssResource extends CssResource {
    String className();
}
```

And when I add the sprite to the css file,

```
@sprite .className {
    gwt-image: 'image';
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
[ERROR] - Unable to find ImageResource method value("image") in
com.example.client.views.MyView_BinderImpl_GenBundle : Could not find 
no-arg method named image in type com.example.views.MyView_BinderImpl_GenBundle
```

Comment: Are you referencing `mystyle.css` from anywhere other than your ClientBundle? Do you have a `<ui:style>` reference in `MyView.ui.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I am referencing mystyle.css from both, the ClientBundle and the UiBinder. I have the following reference: `<ui:style src="../resource/css/mystyle.css" />`
Do I need to reference it from other places also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your styles from UiBinder templates as follows:

```
<ui:with type="com.example.client.resource.ResourceBundle" field="myResource"/>

<g:FlowPanel styleName="{myResource.myCssResource.className}"/>
```

Comment: Yep, I already access the `ImageResource` from my `UiBinder` in the same way you are showing here.
But what I cannot do now is access the ImageResource from external .css files, as is shown in the [CssResourceCookBook](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResourceCookbook) section **Background images / Sprites**

Comment: Can you post the contents of `MyView.ui.xml` in your question? I'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: Well, as I wrote in the original question, I can access the `ImageResource` from MyView.ui.xml in the following way:
`<ui:with type="com.example.client.resource.ResourceBundle" field="myResource"/>
<g:Image resource="{myResource.image}"/>`
And also don't have problems assigning style class names from the CssResource:
`<g:Label styleName="{style.className}" />`

The problem arises when trying to set a `background-image` property in the file `mysstyle.css` using the @sprite notation.

Comment: You need to access the CssResource through the UiBinder template's reference to the ClientBundle - it won't work if you load the CSS file with `<ui:style>`. So instead of `<g:Label styleName="{style.className}"/>` you will use `<g:Label styleName="{myResource.myCssResource.image}"/>`.

Comment: Great! I have it working now. Thanks a lot @Jason! Just a detail; in your last comment it should said `<g:Label styleName="{myResource.myCssResource.className}"/>`

Comment: Just a note to say that `@sprite` work OK in `<ui:style>`, as UiBinder just generates an implicit `ClientBundle` and `CssResource` out of it. The way to add an `ImageResource` to that implicit `ClientBundle` (the `*_GenBundle` in the error message) is to use a `<ui:image>` in the `ui.xml`. There's also `<ui:data>` to generate a `DataResource`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Actually, if I understood correctly, ui:image doesn't use an ImageResource, you have to specify a relative path to the image name, you cannot reference the resource itself. It sucks because it gets in the way of refactoring, abstracting paths, etc. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5320 bug about the issue. If I missed something about ui:image, I would be glad to be corrected! ^_^'